# Custom buttons or TextView onClick or other method to solve android layout issue?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I need to create a list of buttons like these, but I don't know how to implement this, there are few options make buttons, but I don't think I can make buttons like this, if I use textview will it work? Is there any other option?

[image: layout]

Is there any gui editor for android? Or can i make rectangle class and inside that class someone click to fire the event?

Comment: y u r saying that u can't make buttons like this?

Comment: i think you should use transparent view for button background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a button appear anyway you want.  See these examples:

http://inphamousdevelopment.wordpress.com/2010/10/05/creating-easy-custom-buttons-in-android/

http://androidcookbook.oreilly.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=0A9B6292F90D72D302B58DD4680BC0BC?recipeId=3307&recipeFrom=ViewTOC

Answer (score 1):

Custom buttons in a LinearLayout would certainly do the trick.  But when I see that screen shot, I also think ListView.  That might be an interesting and scalable way to lay these out.